# Whats wrong with my emailing code?

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, sendmail, with-statement

This is my code:

```
Public Class form1

Sub SendMail()
    Dim iMsg As Object
    Dim iConf As Object
    Dim Flds As Object
    iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
    iConf.Load(-1) ' CDO Source Defaults
    Flds = iConf.Fields
    With Flds
        .Item("http://schemas.Microsoft.Com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
        .Item("http://schemas.Microsoft.Com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.Microsoft.Com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "myemail@gmail.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.Microsoft.Com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "mypassword"
        .Item("http://schemas.Microsoft.Com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.Microsoft.Com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.Microsoft.Com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        .Update()
    End With

    With iMsg
        .Configuration = iConf
        .To = "obroomhall@gmail.com"
        .From = "obroomhall@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "subject"
        .TextBody = "test"
        .Send()
    End With

End Sub

End Class
```

Obviously I change myemail and mypassword to what I need them to be, but this returns no error codes nor does it send an email! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why use the ancient CDO instead of using System.Net.Mail classes?

Comment: i didnt know any other way, can you please give me an example @JohnSaunders ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

Answer (score 1):

smtp.gmail.com uses port 465 for SSL connections.

Comment: why would that change anything? Is that port normally blocked by computers?

Comment: port 25 is for unencrypted traffic (unless client uses STARTTLS command)